# FileNotFoundError: [Error 2] No such file or directory: "DOB.txt, VS Code, Python

Tags: python, file, filenotfounderror

I am new to Python and I would appreciate all the help I can get.
I'm working in VS Code and I have my Dropbox open in Explorer. I have my text file, `DOB.txt` in the same folder as my code but when I try to read from it, I get the error message above. There is probably a simple solution that I can't see?
Also downloaded files to my desktop and tried to run it from there but with no luck. Also tried to run it with absolute path.

My code so far:

```
with open("DOB.txt" , "r") as file:     
lines = file.readlines() 
print(lines)
```

Comment: Replace `"path/to/your/script_and_DOB.txt_folder"` with the actual path
`os.chdir("path/to/your/script_and_DOB.txt_folder")`

Comment: _I have my text file, DOB.txt in the same folder as my code_ That is not enough.  When you call `open("DOB.txt" , "r")`, it looks in the **current directory**, which might not be the same as your code module.

Comment: _Also tried run it with absolute path_ Show us that exact code.

Comment: with open("C:\Users\mycha\OneDrive\Desktop\DOB.py\DOB.txt" , "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    print(lines)

Comment: Surely there isn't an actual subdirectory named `...\DOB.py\...`

Comment: DOB.py is just a folder name on my Desktop. I ran my code from my Desktop with below suggestion and it worked!!! Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DOB.py` appears to be file containing your python code. You are probably mistaking it as the name of the folder containing your text file. I wouldn't want to think that you named your directory DOB.py. To resolve your issue, please verify your actual file path and then use:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\mycha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\FolderContainingYourTextFile\\DOB.txt" , "r") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    print(lines)
```

**NB:** If your text file is saved directly on your Desktop, then your file path should be `"C:\\Users\\mycha\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\DOB.txt"` But again, one wonders if your Desktop is a subdirectory on OneDrive. Please verify your actual filepath.

Comment: Thank you!! its working now. I went through my course material and no ware there is a mention about double slashes in my path... Thanks again!